# I couldn't find the requested endpoint

Tags: wallet, transaction, api

When I try to construct a transaction by following the [Cardano Wallet Backend API (v2021-06-11)](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/) (Transaction New section) by writing this code in TypeScript:

```
const resp: Response = await fetch(`http://localhost:1338/v2/wallets/${senderWalletId}/transactions-construct`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            payments: {
                address: sendToWalletAdress,
                amount: {
                    quantity: tADAToSend,
                    unit: "lovelace"
                }

            },
        })
    });
```

I got this response:

```
{
  message: "I couldn't find the requested endpoint. If the endpoint contains path parameters, please ensure they are well-formed, otherwise I won't be able to route them correctly.",
  code: 'not_found'
}
```

Is `transactions-construct` not yet implemented or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the `senderWalletId` correctly formatted?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't even get to that point because /transactions-construct part does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for `transactions-construct` [has been added just some days ago](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/commit/c2f658aede557c01fc53711e3ffe8b4dea76cd21) and is not released yet.